# How do I create a reusable select component with react that I can use with almost any type of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have reusable select component I made with react-select and I wish to reuse this component each type I require a select dropdown in my form. Currently, it works with a specific set of data but I want to be able to use it with data from different API endpoints.

Here is the component

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

const MySelect = ({ closeMenuOnSelect = false, options, defaultValue, isMulti = false, label, placeholder, onChange }) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue)
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState("")

    const handleChange = (option) => {
        setSelected(option.value)
        console.log(option)
    }
    
    return(
        <div className='multi-select'>
            <label>{label}</label>
            <Select
                isMulti={isMulti}
                options={options}
                value={options.find(function (option) {
                    return option.value === selected
                })}
                onChange={handleChange} 
                defaultValue={value}
                closeMenuOnSelect={closeMenuOnSelect}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                hideSelectedOptions={true}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default MySelect
```

and here is an instance that works

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {handleRegistration(e)}}>
    <div className="divider">
        <p>Your Details</p>
    </div>

    <div className="flex-item">
       <Input label={'Other name(s)'} type={'text'} value={student.middleName} />
       <MySelect options={Genders} label={'Gender'} closeMenuOnSelect={true} />
    </div>
</form>
```

where `Genders` looks like this

```
export const Genders = [
    {value: 'Male', label: "Male"},
    {value: 'Female', label: "Female"},
]
```

I have a function `getClassList` where fetch from an api endpoint and in place of `value` and `label` on the response, I have `sectionName` and `description` respectively. The error I get is `options.find is not a function` although the type of the response is an Object

Here is the fucntion i use to fetch the classes

```
import axios from "axios"

export const getClassList = (data) => {
    axios.get('/getClassList.php', {
        header: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    })
    .then((res) => {
        return data(res.data)
    })
    .catch((ex) => {
        console.log(ex)
    })
}
```

and this is where I set the classList

```
  const [classList, setClassList] = useState([])
  console.log(classList)

  useEffect(() => {
    getClassList(setClassList)

  }, []);
```

Wow, this question is long, I hope I made sense. Please assist where, even if it means rewriting the whole logic

I have tried using `map` instead of `find` but when I do that, it returns an empty object and the select dropdown says`**No Options**`as soon as I select the first option, which is empty as well

Comment: "The error I get is options.find is not a function although the type of the response is an Object".

'options' prop is expected to be of array type. Since the response you receive from the other API is an Object, the error is encountered. 'find' method is available on Arrays and not Objects. Try parsing the response into an array of objects with 'value' and 'label' properties and it would start populating the data into the select component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I will try to provide as much context as I can. So, I created a new `Select` input from scratch with html and iterated through the `classList` with `Array.prototype.map` with the help of [MDN Web Docs] and it works just fine. This is how it would look like:

```
<select
                  className="multi-select"
                  ref={studClassRef}
                  onChange={(e) => setStudentClass(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <option value="">Select...</option>
                  {classList.map((listItem) => (
                    <option
                      key={listItem.sectionName}
                      value={listItem.sectionName}
                    >
                      {listItem.sectionName}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
```

I did a little research though on iterating through `react-select` with custom `value:label` properties and I found out that you can use `getOptionLabel` and `getOptionValue` to display the options in a manner at which your data object is structured like so:

```
 options={student.coursesBag}
 getOptionValue={(option) => option.courseCode}
 getOptionLabel={(option) => option.courseName}
```

Here's the complete component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactSelect from "react-select";

class MultiSelect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedOptions: {},
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOptions: e });
  };

  render() {
    const student = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("student"));

    return (
      <div className="multi-select">
        <label>{this.props.label}</label>
        <ReactSelect
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          isMulti
          options={student.coursesBag}
          getOptionValue={(option) => option.courseCode}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.courseName}
          closeMenuOnSelect={false}
          hideSelectedOptions={true}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          isOptionDisabled={() => this.state.selectedOptions.length >= 7}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MultiSelect;
```